# Installed Meteor 1.4 not working, 1.3 was working perfectly

Tags: node.js, meteor, windows-10, angular-meteor

I installed the latest version of meteor from the installer on the site. I am running Windows 10.

Meteor was working perfectly for me and I had developed a number of sites. However, I updated and now I can't run meteor anywhere. It gives me the following error:

[image: Meteor problem]

Comment: Why are you running it from the system32 directory? You should be running it from your project's root.

Comment: Because when you install 1.4 it tells you to run it from as admin first. It wouldn't run through the project root.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was quite easy actually, just need to re-install Node and everything works as before!